# insert date in bulk in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, bulk

I'm trying to import users in a table with that sql query :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TEST.dbo.SALARIES;
INSERT INTO TEST.dbo.SALARIES
  (PSA_SALARIE,PSA_LIBELLE,PSA_PRENOM,PSA_DATESORTIE)
    SELECT Matricule,Nom,Prenom,Date_sortie
      FROM  OPENROWSET(BULK 'E:\...\infoprofuniq.txt',
      FORMATFILE='E:\...\infoprof.fmt',
      FIRSTROW = 1,
      CODEPAGE = 'ACP'
) as t1 ;
```

Here is the fmt file I'm using :

```
9.0
4
1   SQLCHAR 0   0   ";" 1   Matricule   ""
2   SQLCHAR 0   0   ";" 2   Prenom  ""
3   SQLCHAR 0   0   ";" 3   Nom ""
4   SQLDATETIME 0   0   "\r\n"  4   Date_sortie ""
```

Here is a sample of datas I'm trying to import :

```
000001;JOHN;DOE;'2001-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

I'm getting the error (through google translate since I use a french version of sql server) :

```
Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Error converting the bulk load data (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 4 (Date_sortie).
```

I've tried using single quote, double quotes, none and different date format but I can't figure out what format is SQL Server waiting for.

PSA_DATESORTIE is a "datetime" type allowing null values.

Did someone ever run into this problem ?
Help greatly appreciated !
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Data format is different depending on your language. Since you mentioned you're running the French version of SQL Server, that means

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-20-11')
```

will work just fine for you but

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2015-11-20')
```

will return an error. Yes?

Try manually inserting a few rows from your dataset and see which format works. The sample row you provided '2001-01-01 00:00:00.000' isn't helpful because it doesn't have a value that will exceed the max value of month (12). Find a few rows from your dataset that has date values where the day is greater than 12 (like the example above).

Also, make sure nulls in the dataset really has no value instead of the string 'null'. Finally, if all checks out fine, look into possible special/unprintable characters hidden in the dataset.

Comment: I didn't have the chance to test it out as I finally could insert using this format '2015-31-12 23:59:59.999'. Thanks though for your answer and yes I did find a lot of special/unprintable characters in the dataset !